# Changing the color of a label's backcolor with a variable for the label's name

Tags: vb.net

so I have a problem regarding trying to change the back colour of a label. I have 49 labels in a game we are making at school. Each label is named from 1 to 49 as "LabelTile1" "LabelTile2" "LabelTile3" etc. I am now trying to connect the player's score and "LabelTile" to create eg "LabelTile9" I got that much working but then I made a variable called LabelTileNameGenerator to store the "LabelTile9" variables created and then use 
`LabelTileNameGenerator.BackColor =System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(&HC0FFC0)`
But I get told thatBackColor is not a member of string.

Is there a better way of doing this than to write 150 lines of code together for each possible score and to then light up that tile?`Public Class Form1
    Dim RoundCounter As Integer
    Dim Player1Score As Integer
    Dim Player2Score As Integer
    Dim LabelTileNameGenerator
    Dim hello As Object

```
Private Sub ButtonRollDice_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonRollDice.Click
    Dim Rolled, Rolled2, RolledTotal As Integer
    Dim oDice As New Random()
    Dim Player As String


    Rolled = oDice.Next(1, 7)
    Rolled2 = oDice.Next(1, 7)

    RolledTotal = Rolled + Rolled2

    If RoundCounter Mod 2 = 0 Then
        Player = 1

        LabelRolledScores.Text = "Player " & Player & " got a " & Rolled & " and a " & Rolled2 & " together that gives you " & RolledTotal

        Player1Score = Player1Score + RolledTotal
        LabelP1Score.Text = "Player 1 current score : " & Player1Score
        '.Name function used before it is set to a value
        hello = "LabelTile" & Player1Score
        LabelTileNameGenerator = hello
        LabelTileNameGenerator.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(&HC0FFC0)

    End If
    If RoundCounter Mod 2 = 1 Then
        Player = 2

        LabelRolledScores.Text = "Player " & Player & " got a " & Rolled & " and a " & Rolled2 & " together that gives you " & RolledTotal

        Player2Score = Player2Score + RolledTotal
        LabelP2CurrentScore.Text = "Player 2 current score : " & Player2Score


    End If
    RoundCounter = RoundCounter + 1
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    RoundCounter = 0
    Player1Score = 1
    Player2Score = 1
End Sub
```

End Class
[Image of Naming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WOdt.jpg)

[Image of GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6xRo.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing all these labels by name is not a good option (creating them with names in the first place is not a good option either, but this is another pair of shoes). But you can still do that. The problem you are encountering is that you want to change something of the label but you only have the label's name. And of course, a name does not have a background color.

You could do something like this:

```
'We assume that this control exists and that it is a label. If you cannot assert that, you
'should add appropriate exception handling.
Dim tileLabel = CType(Me.Controls("LabelTile" & Player1Score), Label)
tileLabel.BackColor = '...
```

This code snippet finds the control with the given name (`"LabelTile" & Player1Score`) in the current form's controls collection. The type of the returned object is `Control`. If you just want to change the background color, you can leave the cast away (because `Control` has a `BackColor`). If you want to access a `Label`-specific property, you need to cast the returned object to type `Label` as shown in the snippet. Without the cast, it would look like this:

```
Dim tileLabel = Me.Controls("LabelTile" & Player1Score)
tileLabel.BackColor = '...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was having trouble with trying to cut down the code to this small amount as my peers each did 150 lines of code for this task.

Comment: What happens if the control is ***not*** found, specifically trying to access a member of an object? It would make sense if checking it does find something before trying to access any of its members...

Comment: If the control does not exist, the returned object is `Nothing`. So you can check `If tileLabel IsNot Nothing`. And you can also check the type before casting: `If TypeOf tileLabel Is Label`.